# Interfacing a cpython extension with a C struct

Tags: python, c, cpython, python-extensions

I am trying to create a python extension to interface python with my C software. Mainly I need to made a big struct from C software accessible and modifiable in python, so I would like to create a Python class to do the intermediate, eg so that doing in python `my_class.var_int = 1` would be reflected on the subjacent struct.

So I made a simple Python object, with the following subjactent data

```c
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    struct my_struct *struct_data; 
} CustomObject;
```

The problem is that with this method I need to define a getter and setter function for each field in my struct, which is huge (~300) even if there are mainly primitive fields such as `int` or `double`. And writing that many function will be error-prone and not very evolutive.

There is the simple method to define class member stored directly from in the Object struct :

```c
static PyMemberDef Custom_members[] = {
    {"var_int1", T_INT, offsetof(CustomObject, var_int1), 0,
     "first name"},
    {"var_int2", T_int, offsetof(CustomObject, var_int2), 0,
     "last name"},
    {"var_double", T_DOUBLE, offsetof(CustomObject, var_doube), 0,
     "custom number"},
    {NULL}  
};
```

But in my case it won't work since the variables are not stored directly in the Object struct, but in a struct referenced by the Object.

Is there any simpler way to interface a struct with Python. Or am I stuck to define a getter and setter function for each of my struct field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to use `PyMemberDef` you need to change the memory layout of your class (`struct_data` is no longer pointer):

```c
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    struct my_struct struct_data; 
} CustomObject;
```

and now `offsetof` can be used again:

```c
static PyMemberDef Custom_members[] = {
    {"var_int1", T_INT, offsetof(CustomObject, struct_data.var_int1), 0,
     "first name"},
     ...
    {NULL}  
};
```

As the `offset` in the `PyMemberDef`-definition should be the same for all instances of class `CustomObject`, it cannot depend on the address stored in the pointer `struct_data`.

So if there is no really good reason, why `struct_data` must be a pointer, the above solution has multiple advantages (less code, no memory management needed and so on).

Comment: They already know about this.